# split sentences in pandas df into rows of words and number each sentence

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split, unnest

I am new to python and I have a pandas dataframe that looks like below:

```
df =
sn  sent                                                    ent
0   ['an', 'apple', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'what?']   ['O', 'F', '0', '0', '0', 'O', 'O']
1   ['a', 'potato', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'what?']   ['O', 'V', '0', '0', '0', 'O', 'O']
```

I want to create another pandas dataframe that looks like below:

```
newdf= 
sn  sent        ent
0   an          O
    apple       F
    is          O
    an          O
    example     O
    of          O
    what?       O
1   a           O
    potato      V
    is          O
    an          O
    example     O
    of          O
    what?       O
```

I tried this code and ended up with what is shown below the code

```
df.set_index('sn')
            .stack()
            .str.split(expand=True)
            .stack()
            .unstack(level=1)
            .reset_index(level=0, drop=0)
```

It's close, to what I want, but can seem to figure out the rest

```
sn  sent        ent
0   ['an',      ['O',
0   'apple',    'F',
0   'is',       'O',
0   'an',       'O',
0   'example',  'O',
0   'of',       'O',
0   'what?',    'O',
1   'a',        'O',
1   'potato',   'V',
1   'is',       'O',
1   'an',       'O',
1   'example',  'O',
1   'of',       'O',
1   'what?']    'O']
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated

Comment: Try with explode and concat the result ~

Comment: you can also try with explode+join  `df.join([df[i].explode() for i in ['sent','ent']])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'sn': [0,1],
                  'sent': [['an', 'apple', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'what?'], ['a', 'potato', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'what?']],
                  'ent': [['O', 'F', '0', '0', '0', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'V', '0', '0', '0', 'O', 'O']]})

df.apply(pd.Series.explode).set_index('sn')
```

Result:

```py
       sent ent
sn             
0        an   O
0     apple   F
0        is   0
0        an   0
0   example   0
0        of   O
0     what?   O
1         a   O
1    potato   V
1        is   0
1        an   0
1   example   0
1        of   O
1     what?   O
```